# I would like to have a quote page just to show quotes

Tags: post-formats, genesis-theme-framework

I want to have quotes just show quotes and not the featured image like this https://demo.zigzagpress.com/xplorer/category/post-format-quote/ how would I go about stripping away the other things and keep it that way.  I am using genesis framework Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would use the class "category-post-format-quote" that is on the body tag to target and hide each element with CSS.

For example, you could hide the sidebar by the following CSS.

```
.category-post-format-quote .sidebar {
    display: none;
}
```

Use your browser's inspector (F12) and find all the elements you want to hide.

Comment: thanks but would that have the category page like in that demo. You just have the category showing quotes post but there are no links to the post itself. it just outputs the quote